# How to generate random numbers in python without built in function and save it in a list

Tags: python

This is what i have tried

```
    def random(start,end):
        start = int(start)
        end = int(end)
        list_sec = datetime.datetime.now()
        last_el=str(list_sec).split('.')[-1]
        len_str=len(str(end))
        get_number_elements = last_el[-int(len_str):]
        try:
            if int(get_number_elements)<=end and int(get_number_elements)>=start:
                return get_number_elements
            else:
                max_value = int('9'*len_str)
                res = start+int(get_number_elements)*(end-start)/(max_value)
                list_elements = []
                list_elements.append(res)
                print('Element = ',list_elements)
                return int(list_elements)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    for num in range(5):
        rand_number = random(5,100)
        sleep(1)
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? You could try to add in some modulos into your function. Look how SHA256 works, try to replicate a little, and input the time in it.

Comment: I cant save all the values in a list

Comment: Why is that?, in your for loop, you can just do myList.append(random(5,100)) ? No? And why do you want a custom random value generator?

Comment: This. Creating good pseudorandom numbers is _hard_. Like cryptography, this should not be homebrewed. There should never be a reason not to use the built-in PRNG (unless you need and have a better source of (pseudo)randomness).

Comment: @Benliam12 I need to save all values in single list but myList.append(random(5,100)) saves each element and replaces the new one

Comment: You've made a good start, but you can help others help you by explaining a little about where you are trying to go with this.

Comment: One of the problems with making your own random number generator, is that you are eliminating the one aspect that make "random" number generators seemingly random: "You don't know the formula that they are using to generate the numbers". In computing, nothing is truly random, since computers behave in the exact way program them to do. If you want random data, use numpy or random libraries and set a random seed.

Comment: @RobertDodier My task is to generate a list of random numbers without using builtin functions and save the generated elements in a list

Comment: Look where you create your `list_elements`. It is set to `[]`, then you append some values and next time it is set as empty list again. Move the setup of the list at the beginning of your function.

Comment: ETR, thanks for the additional information. Sounds like Jacob helped you solve this problem, but if you post additional questions, my advice is to put that additional information in the problem statement so that every reader sees it first.